# Re-render flatlist data when item is pressed

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I using a react-native flatlist to render my data. I want to re-render data in flatlist when an item is pressed inside flatlist. How to achieve this?

```
  const data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: 'First Item',
        isShow: 0
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Second Item',
        isShow: 0
    }]
       
    const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => onPress(item}>
                <Text>{item.title}</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity/>
              );
    };

    const onPress = (item) => {
        item.isShow = 1;
    }

    <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={renderItem}
        keyExtractor={item => item.id}
    />
```

when `item.isShow = 1` flatlist data should re-render.

Comment: Take a look at https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#forceupdate

Comment: you could use `useState(data)` and `setState(...)`, this will trigger a re-render. Keep in mind that you should not directly mutate values of an object because React can't track those changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your data used in the FlatList must be a state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

In your `onPress` method you must do like this

```
 const onPress = (item) => {
  const newData =  data.map(dataWithIsShow=> {
     if(dataWithIsShow.id === item.id) {
       dataWithIsShow.isShow = 1
       return dataWithIsShow;
     }
     return dataWithIsShow
   } ) 
   setData(newData)
    }
```

Got it? Please if you have more doubts you can ask :).